# Reverse lexicographic sort as a final sorting process of a list

Tags: python, sorting

Given `list = [('a',1),('b',3),('c',2)]`, how can I incorporate a lexicographical sort on the `str` elements on this `lambda` function I've written:

```
list.sort(key = lambda x: ((s - x[1] if x[1] < s else x[1] - s), x[1], len(x[0])))
```

Where `(s - x[1] if x[1] < s else x[1] - s)` sorts the `int` elements by how close they are to an integer `s`, and the succeeding sorting process are done if the preceding sorting process leads to a tie in value. Now I want to add a reverse lexicographical sort as a final sorting process and an easy approach is to use a `reverse` parameter in the sort method, but of course it is only applicable if it is the only sorting method I will  use, I don't know how to do it in my case.

Comment: `abs(s-x[1])` looks easier than `(s - x[1] if x[1] < s else x[1] - s)`

Comment: There is either `functools.cmp_to_key` which allows to write a compare function instead of a key function where this can be implemented. Or a simple but inefficient way is to first do the reverse lexicographical sort and then apply the sort you already have. This works because the sort function in Python is stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use some crazy UTF-8 characters, the following should work:

```
>>> a = ['b', 'c', 'g', 'f']
>>> sorted(a, key = lambda x : 255-ord(x))
['g', 'f', 'c', 'b']
```

so your final sort function will look like:

```
sort(key = lambda x: (abs(s-x[1]), x[1], len(x[0]), (255-ord(i) for i in x[0])))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention a crucial point, the `str` can be a word such as `cat`.

Comment: @Minuet yes, please see the updated answer, string becomes a tuple